# Unable to call asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voximal

I try to get the softphone connected to our instance for playing with our app, but I fail to get the password.

In the [web Interface](https://wiki.voximal.com/doku.php?id=installation_guide:softphone:start) no password is mentioned.

And for the asterisk console, I got no access to the cli, did an error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

The password for the trial package is the first block of the UID (the first 8 characters) :[image]

By default, a IAX user peer is created with those credentials.
It allows you to place call from a simple SoftPhone (using IAX protocol).